# How to get a telegram bot work in a channel?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I can't get it to work through properties like command or just content_types. No errors show up.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(msg:Message):
    if msg.chat.type == ChatType.CHANNEL:
        await msg.answer(msg)
```

I made so bot sent a message to the channel. Still nothing.

P.S It works with getUpdates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Dispatcher class there is a decorator called "channel_post_handler".